# Zend Framework + Doctrine1.2 project structure with more modules

Tags: zend-framework, structure, doctrine-1.2

applications coupled with the realization ZendFramework + Doctrine 1.2 for some time, but now they have their first experience with the use of more modules. I requested a default module is visible to everyone with a certain layout and an admin module with a different layout.

So far in my applications I have always used the following structure:

```
/app
    /application
        /acls
        /configs
        /controllers
        /forms
        /layouts
        /models --> models by doctrine
            /generated --> base models by doctrine
        /plugins
        /views
        /Bootstrap.php
    /data
    /doctrine
        /data
        /migrations
        /schema
            /schema.yml
        /doctrine.php
    /library
    /public
    /tests
```

So my question is: how should the structure of my application to do what is required?

I tried using zend tool and see what kind of structure I created the command:

```
zf create module admin
```

course after launching

```
zf create project app
```

I noticed that the create command module I created a folder `modules` in `application`.
Into `modules` created `admin` and inside it has created `controllers`, `models` and `views`.

So in addition to separating means zf controller and view correctly, but also models. 
But my doctrine creates all the models on the one hand! :D

How can I do to use templates created by doctrine for each module?

Then how do I assign a new layout for the admin module?

For the party guest you advise me to leave the facility that currently use or move it all in a form `default`?

Sorry if I made a lot of questions, maybe too much, but I am really very confused about it!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### After a thorough documentation I've found the right project structure

```
/app
/application
    /acls
    /configs
        application.ini
    /layouts
        /scripts
            admin.phtml
            default.phtml
    /models --> models by doctrine
        /generated --> base models by doctrine
    /modules
        /admin
            /controllers
            /forms
            /view
        /default
            /controllers
            /forms
            /view
    /plugins
    /Bootstrap.php
/data
/doctrine
    /data
    /migrations
    /schema
        /schema.yml
    /doctrine.php
/library
/public
/tests
```

### To view a different layout according to where you are module I used the following plugins:

```
class Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Called before an action is dispatched by Zend_Controller_Dispatcher.
     *
     * @param  Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        switch ($module) {
            case 'default':
                $layout->setLayout('default');
                break;
            case 'admin':
                $layout->setLayout('admin');
                break;
            default:
                $layout->setLayout('default');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**into Bootstrap.php file**

```
 /**
 * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
 */
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    $autoloader->addResourceType('plugin', 'plugins', 'Plugin');
    return $autoloader;
}
```

**into application.ini file**

```
resources.frontController.plugins.auth = Plugin_Layout
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

the plugin described above according to the module in use will set the layout with the name of module.phtml within "layouts/scripts".

---

### How to Autoload forms within a module

add the two below lines to your application.ini file

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Create a boostrap file for each module.  The file, named Bootstrap.php, should be placed in the root of the module directory and the class name should be {module name}_Boostrap. This bootstrap file will cause zend framework to automatically add the new forms directory to the autoloader.

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

Add for form class to the /forms directory. A login form would have a filename of Login.php and a class name of {module name}_Form_Login

```
class Admin_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
```

Call your form from a controller file from within the same module

```
$form = new Admin_Form_Login();
```

Simple and effective! ;)

Comment: To make it more clear your answer is the solution as well accept your answer!

Comment: @KeesSchepers is precisely what I did. I had received no response after several days and then I found the answers elsewhere. Then I thought of writing as a response so that it can serve to someone else later.
I was wrong?

Comment: @KeesSchepers: Can I do it? It is against the rules?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have seen more people advising it and doing it so it consider it's allowed or even suggested. Check this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/